# Unable to compile library, symbol not found when running make

Tags: macos, github, makefile, cmake, macos-catalina

I am trying to compile a library, MultiNest. I am on Mac OS Catalina, 10.15.6. The instructions to do so are

```
git clone https://github.com/JohannesBuchner/MultiNest
cd MultiNest/build
cmake ..
make
```

I get this error when running make:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"___nested_MOD_nestrun", referenced from:
_run in eggbox.c.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [../bin/eggboxC] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/example_eggbox_C/CMakeFiles/eggboxC.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: According to that [bugreport](https://github.com/JohannesBuchner/PyMultiNest/issues/10) with similar error, the project doesn't work with clang.

Comment: I am using gcc. Part of output when running cmake is "The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0", so unless I'm confused about something I don't think clang is used anywhere.